# F# 'The file name is not valid!' when trying File.Move

Tags: f#

I decided to learn F#. One of the programs I write to learn a new language is a "jpg-renamer", A command line app that takes file-paths as args, reads the `DateTimeOriginal` EXIF tag and renames the files using the DateTimeOriginal to `YYYY-MM-dd_hh.mm.ss.jpg` which is a valid filename.

The function that does the actual renaming is this:

```
let renameFile (path:string) =
    let newName = (getOriginalDateTime path |> changeTimeStampString) + Path.GetExtension(path)
    printfn "%s -> %s" <| path <| newName
    File.Move(path, newName)
```

When I run the program, this happens:

```
mono srenamer.exe IMG_20180303_153239.jpg
IMG_20180303_153239.jpg -> 2018-03-03_15.32.40.jpg

Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentException: The file name is not valid.
  at System.IO.File.Move (System.String sourceFileName, System.String 
destFileName) [0x0008d] in <b64e2aa77b4f4d60b739d6ceaf49caa4>:0
  at Srenamer.renameFile (System.String path) [0x0005f] in <5aa45864019ff926a74503836458a45a>:0
  at Srenamer.renameFiles[a](Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[T] paths) [0x00030] in <5aa45864019ff926a74503836458a45a>:0
  at Srenamer.main (System.String[] args) [0x00006] in <5aa45864019ff926a74503836458a45a>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: The file name is not valid.
  at System.IO.File.Move (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName) [0x0008d] in <b64e2aa77b4f4d60b739d6ceaf49caa4>:0
  at Srenamer.renameFile (System.String path) [0x0005f] in <5aa45864019ff926a74503836458a45a>:0
  at Srenamer.renameFiles[a] (Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[T] paths) [0x00030] in <5aa45864019ff926a74503836458a45a>:0
  at Srenamer.main (System.String[] args) [0x00006] in <5aa45864019ff926a74503836458a45a>:0
```

Notice how the `printfn` prints the correct and valid new filename.

As part of my investigation I tried to just put the new filename as a string literal into the code like this:

```
let newName = "2018-03-03_15.32.40.jpg"
File.Move(path, newName)
```

Which works as expected. I also checked `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars` which only returns `/` (Linux).

So why is the string that the code generates an invalid filename when the exact same hardcoded string works just fine?

For reference, here is the entire source code:

```
open System.Drawing
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
open System.IO

/// Changes timestamp string 'yyyy:dd:mm hh:mm:ss' to 'yyyy-mm-dd_hh.mm.ss'.
let changeTimeStampString (dt:string) =
    let t = dt.Split(':', ' ')
    // [yyyy; mm; dd; hh; mm; ss]
    t.[0] + "-" + t.[1] + "-" + t.[2] + "_" + t.[3] + "." + t.[4] + "." + t.[5]

let rec getOrigDateTimeProp (propertyItems:Imaging.PropertyItem list) =
    match propertyItems with
    | x::xs -> match x.Id.ToString("x") with
                | "9003" -> System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString x.Value
                | _-> getOrigDateTimeProp xs
    | [] -> ""

let getOriginalDateTime (path:string) =
    let img = new Bitmap(path)
    let propItems = img.PropertyItems
    getOrigDateTimeProp (propItems |> Array.toList)

let renameFile (path:string) =
    let newName = (getOriginalDateTime path |> changeTimeStampString) + Path.GetExtension(path)
    printfn "%s -> %s" <| path <| newName
    File.Move(path, newName)

let rec renameFiles (paths:string list) =
    match paths with
    | x::xs -> match x with
                | a when Regex.Match(a,@".+\.[jpg|JPG]").Success ->
                    renameFile x
                    renameFiles xs
                | a when Regex.Match(a,@".+\.[mp4|MP4]").Success ->
                    printfn "this is an mp4"
                    renameFiles xs
                | _ -> renameFiles xs
    | [] -> ignore

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args=
    renameFiles (args |> Array.toList)
    0
```

Comment: I see you're driving the filename via `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString` from a byte array. Can you dump those bytes to see what they are?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin the output of `printfn "%A" <| x.Value` where I do the `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString x.Value` is

 `[|50uy; 48uy; 49uy; 56uy; 58uy; 48uy; 51uy; 58uy; 48uy; 51uy; 32uy; 49uy; 53uy;  58uy; 51uy; 50uy; 58uy; 52uy; 48uy; 0uy|]`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin thank you, you pointed me in the right direction. Removing the trailing null-byte fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the actual bytes of the EXIF tag value

```
printfn "%A" <| x.Value
```

shows this:

```
[|50uy; 48uy; 49uy; 56uy; 58uy; 48uy; 51uy; 58uy; 48uy; 51uy; 32uy; 49uy; 53uy; 58uy; 51uy; 50uy; 58uy; 52uy; 48uy; 0uy|]
```

The last character is null. Removing that makes the file name valid. Thanks @FyodorSoikin for pointing me in the right direction.